# Convert unix timestamp in Python to datetime and make 2 Hours behind

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have this code,  recieve a unix timestamp from a server which is 2 hours ahead of my time. My time is SAST and theirs is GMT +2.

I convert this timestamp in python to a readable datetime like this

```
import datetime

unixtimestamp = 1507126064
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtimestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The problem is that this time comes back two hours ahead of me, so what would be the easiest way to minus two hours or make it local time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.timedelta) object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

unix_ts = 1507126064
dt = (datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_ts) - timedelta(hours=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(dt)
```

Comment: seems to have worked like a charm ,do I replace import datetime with from datetime import datetime, timedelta ?

Comment: @AndrewChristopher, as you wish: you are able to import the entire module `datetime` (`import datetime`) OR to import just the needed submodules/objects `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`

Comment: I keep getting errors on `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`

Comment: is this correct  import sys
import datetime
import time
import socket
import struct
import MySQLdb
import subprocess
import glob
from datetime import timedelta

Comment: sorry for all on one line